# String conversion to datetime return incorrect date

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to convert these two dates to `DateTime`: 16/09/2019 15:00:00 - 21/09/2019 09:00:00

but I got an incorrect `DateTime` for both dates:

```
$duration = "16/09/2019 15:00:00 - 21/09/2019 09:00:00";
$duration = explode('-', $duration);
            
$start = strtotime($duration[0]);
$end = strtotime($duration[1]);
echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $start);
echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $end);
```

result:

> 31/Dec/1969 16:00:00
>
> 31/Dec/1969 16:00:00

Comment: output of `echo date("d/M/Y H:i:s",strtotime("08-09-2019 14:00"));` seems ok, output of `echo date("d/M/Y H:i:s",strtotime("08/09/2019 14:00"));` returns August, and not September.

Comment: Or you could change the dateformat from 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'yyyy/mm/dd'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$duration = "16/09/2019 15:00:00 - 21/09/2019 09:00:00";
$duration = explode(' - ', $duration);

$start = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", $duration[0]);
$end = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", $duration[1]);
echo $start->format("d/m/Y H:i:s");
echo $end->format("d/m/Y H:i:s");
```

[strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) expects to be given a string containing an English date format

M (uppercase) in format expect a textual representation of a month, in your case use m (lowercase)

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to set dates like dd-mm-yyyy
Second, use delimiter for explode as like " - "

```
        $duration = "16-09-2019 15:00:00 - 21-09-2019 09:00:00";
        $duration = explode(' - ', $duration);

        $start = strtotime($duration[0]);
        $end = strtotime($duration[1]);
        echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $start);
        echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $end);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Datetime createformatformat](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php)

For example

```
$date = date_create_from_format('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

Output

```
2009-02-15
```

Your answer

```
$duration = "16/09/2019 15:00:00 - 21/09/2019 09:00:00";
$duration = explode(' - ', $duration);



$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y:H:i:s', $duration[0]);
echo $date->getTimestamp();

$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y:H:i:s', $duration[1]);
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

stringtotime accepts an expression with the format yyyy/mm/dd. This order can be achieved with an additional line of code with preg_replace.

```
$duration = "16/09/2019 15:00:00 - 21/09/2019 09:00:00";

$duration = preg_replace('#(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d{4})#',"$3/$2/$1",$duration);

$duration = explode('-', $duration);

$start = strtotime($duration[0]);
$end = strtotime($duration[1]);
echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $start); // 16/Sep/2019 15:00:00
echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $end);   // 21/Sep/2019 09:00:00
```